# Как подключить mssql к php?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql

Скачал dll расширение с сайта майкрософта http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/, подключил в php.ini

> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
> extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
> extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll

Перезагрузил сервер,дальше при попытки подключения к серверу выкидывает ошибку

> Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Что делать?почему не подключается расширение?
Версия php 5.5.1,версия apache 2.4.6,версия сервера SQL Express 2012

Заранее спасибо

Comment: На php 5.4.17 тоже не подключается,thread safety у меня on.Убрал значения,оставил только ts
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
та же ошибка((((

Comment: sqlsrv должен появится после подключения dll но он не появляется..
странно то,что mssql dll  не было изначально в php,хотя в php.ini целый раздел посвящённый параметрам mssql..

Comment: @rusbaron, читайте обнолвенный ответ и документацию

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in P:\Server\www\index.php on line 9
да,я добрался до туда))но толку никакого...dll не подключается к php,в phpinfo() нет сообщения о подключении...не понимаю почему

Comment: значит, либо подключаете не ту библиотеку, либо не в тот php.ini

Comment: Подключил php 5.4.17,работает,php 5.5.1 не подключается вообще никак,хотя действия одни и те же выполнял...видимо из за компиляции VC9 и VC11 это как то связанно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключили всё сразу?

Эти файлы для `PHP 5.4`, о чём намекает `54` в названии файла и "*This release includes support for PHP 5.4.0.*" на странице закачки.

Чтобы определиться с тем, подключать `ts` или `nts` файл посмотрите в `phpinfo()` на параметр `Thread Safety`. Если `Enabled`, то `ts`, иначе `nts`.

И сервер перезапустите.

Там же, в `phpinfo()` поищите `sqlsrv` после подключения.

**UPD:**

Из [Mssql Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php) на [php.net](http://php.net): "*This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.*"

Дальше читать [Accessing SQL Server Databases from PHP](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx) на [MS TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com), откуда можно узнать, что для подключения используется функция [sqlsrv_connect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296161.aspx)

*Либо подключайте драйвер к PDO и пользуйтесь им. Может там всё осталось по-старому.*